# tcc: error: undefined symbol '_GetConsoleWindow@0'

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I'm making a program in C/C++ which must run hidden using this code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
int main(){
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
    . . .
}
```

I really want to use tinyc to compile it because it's much better than gcc (almost, the final executable is much tiny than gcc).
The point is that when I try to compile it using:

```
tcc PROGRAM.c -luser32
```

It makes an error which says:

```
tcc: error: undefined symbol '_GetConsoleWindow@0'
```

But when I use gcc it works! I think I have a missed library but I don't know which one.
Please, some help :)

Comment: *I think I have a missed library but I don't know which one.* did you try googling the name of the function? I found which lib its in right away

Comment: Yes, @Borgleader, I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `GetConsoleWindow` is located in `Kernel32.dll`

Try:

```
tcc PROGRAM.c -luser32 -lkernel32
```

---

EDIT:

tcc's `kernel32.def` is missing the export for `GetConsoleWindow`.

Append the string GetConsoleWindow at the end of the def file located in the `lib` directory inside tcc's installation folder.

Comment: yeah :/ I suppose there's not any way to link it, really? Maybe importing kernel32.def from another compiler?

Comment: err, my answer says what to do, just append that line :)

Answer (score 0):

remove `gdi32.def kernel32.def msvcrt.def user32.def` files from `C:\tcc\lib`; remove all `.def` files from `C:\tcc\lib`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincon.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    HWND hwnd;   
    hwnd = GetConsoleWindow(); 
    HDC hdc;
    hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
    
    printf("console hwnd:  %p\n", hwnd);
    printf("console hdc:  %p\n", hdc);
    
    HPEN hPenNull, hPenBlack, hPenRed, hPenGreen, hPenBlue;
    hPenNull=GetStockObject(NULL_PEN); 
    hPenBlack=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0,0,0)); 
    hPenRed=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(255,0,0));
    hPenGreen=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0,255,0)); 
    hPenBlue=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(0,0,255)); 

    HBRUSH hBrushNull, hBrushBlack, hBrushRed, hBrushGreen, hBrushBlue, hBrushYellow;
    hBrushNull=GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH); 
    hBrushBlack=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0)); 
    hBrushRed=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0)); 
    hBrushYellow=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,0)); 
    hBrushGreen=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0)); 
    hBrushBlue=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,255)); 
    
    SelectObject(hdc, hPenRed);
    SelectObject(hdc, hBrushYellow);
    Ellipse(hdc, 200,50,260,150);

    SelectObject(hdc, hPenNull);
    SelectObject(hdc, hBrushRed);
    Ellipse(hdc, 140, 80, 180, 120);
    
    SelectObject(hdc, hPenBlue);
    SelectObject(hdc, hBrushNull);
    Ellipse(hdc, 280, 50, 340, 150);
    
getch();
}
```

-L"C:\tcc\lib" -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -Wl,-subsystem=console

[image]